# Accidental in Chopin Opus. 69 No. 2

Tags: notation, sheet-music, accidentals

This is an excerpt from Opus. 69 No. 2 by Chopin from the Henle Urtext:

[image]

In the last bar seen in the excerpt, there is a sharp on the A in bass line. Since A is already "sharped" in the key signature, and a double sharped note is usually marked as such, I don't know what to make it of it other then a typo. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

It is an A#. Not A double-#. This is done sometimes to indicate that, yes, I really mean A#, not A. In modern notation, it would have parentheses around it: (#). [Other editions](http://imslp.org/wiki/Waltzes,_Op.69_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)) omit the # entirely.

Answer (score 3):

I'd call it a *Courtesy Accidental*. If the composers meant a double-sharp, he would have marked it as such. A sharp sign added to a note that is already sharped by the key signature does not double sharp it. The sign is meant for clarity only. The omission of the sharp sign would be played the same.

Comment: Idk why they think a courtesy accidental is even needed there though. The harmony here is just switching between tonic and dominant (up to inversions), in the key of B major, so it should be clear that it's A# and not A natural.